# Should I be worried if my A/C ran with the cover on?

Tags: hvac

My wife accidentally switched on the "cool " mode and the a/c was activated, however the cover was still on the unit outside. Ran like this for about 2 hours. I noticed it and turned it off and went outside to remove the cover and it was pretty hot. What damage could have been done? Symptoms I should look for? Should I get a service tech?

Answer (score 4):

It should be fine. Air conditioners remove heat and dump it outside; sounds like the heat got dumped into the cover. Remove the cover, let the unit cool down, and don't do it again. If it stops working, call a service tech.